# how can I delete date in this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have table like this

```
create table tbl_1(
  year int,
  month int, 
 day int
)

insert into tbl_1 values(2009,  11, 30)
insert into tbl_1 values(2010,   3,  4)
insert into tbl_1 values(2011,   5, 13)
insert into tbl_1 values(20011, 12, 24)
```

I want to delete date from 2009-11-30 until 2011-5-13, but I can't because all of columns are int and I can't use this query :

```
delete from tbl_1 
 where year >=2009 
   and year<=2011 
   and month >=11 
   and month <=5 
   and day >=30 
   and day <=13
```

..because: 1 < month < 12 and 1 < day < 30

I know that this is terrible mistake.

I have many table that use this way for save date , please help me I don't have time to delete and recreate all of them.

Comment: Could you re-structure the table to store the date in one field? It would make things a lot easier.

Comment: From the reference to C# in the comments I'd say it's quite likely that this is for SQL Server.

Comment: @Mark: pity, my solution was so elegant. Hope that maybe he is just using MySQL connector. Who am I trying to deceive?…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_1 
WHERE (year * 10000 + month * 100 + day) BETWEEN 20091130 AND 20110513
```

I haven't tested this. I would recommend testing it first on a test system before running it on your production data so that you don't accidentally delete the wrong data.

Comment: @Jasper: But this wouldn't be able to use an index, while yours could.

Comment: thank you this way worked in my sql,and u solved my problem. thank you very much from all

Answer (score 4):

In `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL`:

```
DELETE
FROM    tbl_1
WHERE   (2009, 11, 30) <= (year, month, date)
        AND (year, month, date) <= (2011, 5, 13)
```

In `PostgreSQL` you can even do:

```
DELETE
FROM    tbl_1
WHERE   (year, month, date) BETWEEN (2009, 11, 30) AND (2011, 5, 13)
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works please> If (a,b,c) < (x,y,z) is just a shorthand way of saying a < x and b < y and c < z then I don't think this is correct. If that's not the case then I'd like to know more about this syntax.

Comment: that took a few re-reads this late in the day. Thanks for the link. Not sure I follow the partial order thing but I understand cartesian products and I believe can see how that would work now. It's actually quite similar to @Mark's answer then.

Comment: @Chris Simpson: My answer uses only standard SQL. This is vendor specific and I think it's unlikely to work on the OPs system (most likely SQL Server). But I +1ed this answer anyway.

Comment: @Chris: Unfortunately, simple English version is not yet there. But @Jasper's answer illustrates the principle quite well, mine one is just formulated more elegantly (though it won't work in `SQL Server`)

Answer (score 3):

Just use some more boolean operators:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_1
WHERE (year = 2009 AND (month > 11 OR (month = 11 AND day >= 30)))
OR year = 2010
OR (year = 2011 AND (month < 5 OR (month = 5 AND day <= 13)))
```

Not pretty, but it works.

**Edit:**

parametrized:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_1
WHERE (year = %minYear% AND (month > %minMonth% OR (month = %minMonth% AND day >= %minDay%)))
OR (year > %minYear% AND year < %maxYear%)
OR (year = %maxYear% AND (month < %maxMonth% OR (month = %maxMonth% AND day <= %maxDay%)))
```

Comment: tank you for your helping,but i use C# program and  user  select date and this query is limited ,just for 2009 until 2011 and I won't know which date the user select.

Comment: That makes it only slightly harder. It's some work, but it is doable to change this into a parameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the columns to date in your where clause then:

```
DELETE tbl_1
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), year) + '-' + convert(VARCHAR(2), month) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), day)) BETWEEN '20091130' AND '20110513'
```

Comment: when I used this query in sql server,it showed error to me

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
what can I do?

Comment: that's strange. the BETWEEN '20091130' AND '20110513' is using implicit conversion that will fail this way if invalid dates are used. Perhaps you are missing digits from one of these? Alternatively do you have any rows in the table that do not form a valid date?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to use DATE_FORMAT. Like so:

```
...
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(year,"-",month,"-",day), '%Y-%m-%d' ) > "2009-11-30"
AND DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(year,"-",month,"-",day), '%Y-%m-%d' ) < "2011-05-13"
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: I use sql server 2008 and it said :Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. 
this function is difrence in 2008?